# what's the better way to create a state machine in VHDL (if statement or when)

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

I was writing a code for a project, and wondered what's the best code practice to write VHDL state machine :

is it :

```
if(state = state1) then
   do_something;
elsif(state = state2) then
   do_something;
elsif(state = state3) then
   etc ...
end if;
```

or :

```
case state
  when state1 =>
      do_someting;
  when state2 =>
      do_something;
  etc ...
end case;
```

In term of readability, code efficiencty, what's the best ?

Comment: Code efficiency should be the same.

Comment: The noun best (the best) doesn't quantify by itself. Neither does efficiency, and readability is a quality indicating either legibility or being decipherable, or easy and enjoyable to read. These relate to writing style and not the VHDL standard itself, which exhibits cramped style in other elements than yours. Style can be dictated organizationally, solicited reader opinions intersects with that. While you're soliciting opinions on style I find superfluous parentheses enclosing a condition to detract from readability and can interfere with implicit condition operators.

Answer (score 0):

Either. With caveats.

As states are mutually disjoint (you cannot be in State 1 and State 2 simultaneously) the semantics are identical (unlike other uses of "If" which prioritise the first branch).

Either way, don't ignore completeness ("else" or "when others") even if  "else null" is only there to satisfy the verification team you didn't forget about it.

And use safe or robust state machine practice if you are working in a high reliability environment (e.g. where radiation causes SEU state changes and you can't easily put a repairman in orbit)

Comment: case has the advatage of requiring completeness. For example, you add a new state to the type, and forget to add the state in the process, you will get a syntax error (assuming you do not add a `when others =>` clause.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did use the case statement for a better readability (and I didn't forger the case other)

Answer (score 0):

Both of these clearly convey your intent, so that aspect is good.

For synthesis, with `case`, you are telling the synthesis tool that each condition is mutually exclusive.

With `if` you are by default building up a priority structure.  Then you are asking the synthesis tool to figure out the logic is mutually exclusive.

I recommend `case` statements rather than `if` statements for the outer layer of the statemachine - the state decoder.  Likewise for multiplexors.

The concern is that Synthesis is an NP complete process - which means that there is no exact algorithm that always produces the best results - so it hunts.   Eventually it has to stop hunting - one of those factors can be time.

My big picture goal is readable code.  So when a coding style is good for readability and easy for the synthesis tool - like it is with case here, then I tend to use that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did use the case statement for a better readability (and I didn't forger the case other)